# Remote desktop session ended when connect through VPN

Tags: windows-10, vpn, remote-desktop

I'm connecting from my laptop to a remote desktop through a VPN which I do not manage using Windows built-in VPN client with L2TP/IPsec and data encryption enabled.
I can connect to the VPN just fine, but whenever I tried to remote into the desktop, I can only go as far as the login screen. After I enter my username and password, the screen goes black for about 10 seconds then I get the following error.

> Your Remote desktop session has ended. The connection to the remote computer was lost, possibly due to network connectivity problems. Try connecting to the remote computer again. If the problem continues, contact your network administrator or technical support.

The weird thing is if I connect to the VPN network using mobile tethering then I can remote into the desktop just fine, I only have problem with my home WiFi. However, I don't think it is a speed problem because even if I limit my tethering speed to 200kbps, I can still connect to remote desktop, while my home network which is very stable and has good speed always failed. I've also tried to lower resolution, color settings and disabled remote desktop background,... to no avail.

My laptop is a HP Spectre 13, both my laptop and the desktop use Windows 10 Pro with all the latest updates installed. What should I check?

Comment: Have you contacted your network administrator or technical support?

Comment: @Scott I did, the problem seems to only happen on my home WiFi.